# what the opcode.code that represent Logical Condition Operators (&& or || ) in conditional branch C#

Tags: c#

```
public int IS_Conditinal(Mono.Cecil.Cil.OpCode code )
{
    switch (code)
    {
        case Code.Beq:
        case Code.Beq_S:
        case Code.Bge:
        case Code.Bge_S:
        case Code.Bge_Un:
        case Code.Bge_Un_S:
        case Code.Bgt:
        case Code.Bgt_S:
        case Code.Bgt_Un:
        case Code.Bgt_Un_S:
        case Code.Ble:
        case Code.Ble_S:
        case Code.Ble_Un:
        case Code.Ble_Un_S:
        case Code.Blt:
        case Code.Blt_S:
        case Code.Blt_Un:
        case Code.Blt_Un_S:
        case Code.Bne_Un:
        case Code.Bne_Un_S:
        case Code.Brfalse:
        case Code.Brfalse_S:
        case Code.Brtrue:
        case Code.Brtrue_S:
        case Code.Endfilter:
        case Code.Endfinally:
            return 1;
        case Code.And:
        case Code.Or:
           return -1;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}
```

I want to calculate the conditional branch statement, but only when the conditional branch statement that contain Logical Condition Operators
I will count it more than once as it contain logical operators,

```
(case Code.And:
case Code.Or:
   return -1;)
```

dose not solve the problem  because it represent(& , | ) and not represent(&& ,||),please help me very quickly

Comment: && and || do not have representing opcodes. It's represented as multiple comparing branch statements in IL.

Comment: thank You , can you suggest to me ready code or short reference that solve my problem ??

Comment: no  one has reference  about that???

Comment: You can use for example LINQPad or an online alternative to determine to what IL code your C# code will compile. For example you can view IL in https://dotnetfiddle.net/ by opening the dropdown in the top right and clicking View IL.